# Nginx service is not getting removed completely

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nginx

I am using ubuntu 22.04 as the host machine and I am trying to remove nginx completely from the server. I run "sudo apt remove nginx" command but still nginx is shown in systemctl status nginx command.
[Command outputs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K7dIX.png)
I am also not able to to install nginx service back into the machine.
[Out when I am running spt install nginx command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NtS6M.png)

Can someone please help me installing the nginx service.

Tried the things mentioned above but not getting any fruitful outcome.